# Build Pandas dataframe in streaming fashion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large amount of data in binary fashion that I can read in chunks of one or more "rows". I convert these binary rows into rows that can be understood by Pandas. I could read all the binary rows, convert them and store them in a list and then pass this to pd.Dataframe to create a huge dataframe. The problem is that this will store my data twice in memory and I would really like to minimize the maximum memory needed. Is there an efficient way of achieving this? I could imagine there is a way to assign the memory for the Pandas dataframe and fill it up?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but maybe you could use [`numpy.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html), passing a `count` value (you can pass a structured dtype if it is not homogeneous), and then make a data frame from that (it doesn't copy the data by default).

Comment: That looks close to a solution already, so if I have a list of Numpy arrays and I turn that into a DataFrame it doesn't copy the data but uses the reference?

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) has a `copy` parameter (`False` by default) to indicate whether you want to make a copy of the input (copies can be avoided when the data frame is built from another data frame or a NumPy 2D array).

Comment: I did not know the structured dtype but I think that will perfectly solve my issue, thank you! If you turn it in an answer and I implement it tomorrow and it works I will accept it